# Get image size into a global variable before load and ready events

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, size

I've got a problem trying to get an image width and save it into a global var

Im doing this at the momment

```
var imgWidth;

var imgLoad = $("<img />");

imgLoad.attr("src", "Images/animals.jpg");
imgLoad.off("load");
imgLoad.on("load", function () {

  imgWidth = this.width;

  console.log(imgWidth); // It works! Inside function scope

});


console.log(imgWidth); // It doesn't work! Outside function scope
```

I know it's not working because Im trying to show the value outside the scope where the var was set.

The image wont be displayed, I just need the width and height using only a src. I will need the image width and image height in future functions so that's why I need to save it at least into global vars.

How can I solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: You can declare variables out from function (with "var") and in your function/scope you use these variables without var => you declare your variables as global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it imgWidth is undefined outside your function because it is just an empty variable, you don't add nothing to it you are simply declaring it at the top. To make it work you need to do something like this

```
var imgWidth,
    imgLoad = $("<img />");

imgLoad.attr("src", "http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image5_170127819.jpg");

imgLoad.on("load", function () {
  imgWidth = this.width;
  console.log('Inside Function:'+imgWidth);
});

imgWidth = imgLoad[0].width;
console.log('Outside Function:'+imgWidth);
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/kanzvoap/

Comment: Glad that I could help :) Now you can accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Comment: Hello Bojan, just tried you example, and in outside function it's written 0;..so it's not working I think..no?

Answer (score 1):

You have no problem with scope but with timing. The `console.log()` outside the function **does** see the variable `imgWidth`, because its **declared** outside a function. It just has no value assigned so `undefined` is logged. The value (width) becomes assigned **after** the image has been loaded. The load takes some time, but the code does not wait so the last line is executed **before** `imgwidth` has got its value.

Check out the following:

```
var imgWidth;
var demo = 'demoValue';
var imgLoad = $("<img />");

// attach the event-handler BEFORE you set the src-attribute, otherwise it may happen
// that image is loaded before and the onload-function won't work
imgLoad.on("load", function () {
    imgWidth = this.width;
    // all variables declared outside are visible here
    console.log('inside: ', imgWidth); // --> inside: some px
    consolole.log('inside: ', demo); // --> inside: 'demoValue'
});
imgLoad.attr("src", "Images/animals.jpg");

// all variables declared outside a function are also visible here,
// but this runs before the image has finished loading
console.log('outside: ', imgWidth); // --> undefined only because it has no value at this time
console.log('outside: ', demo); // --> 'demoValue'

// now wait a second using a setTimeout
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // all vars are visible here, but now image is loaded and var imgwidth has got its value
    console.log('outsideLater: ' + imgWidth); // --> some px
    console.log('outsideLater: ' + demo); // --> 'demoValue'
}, 1000);
```

So the result is: your var declaration is OK, but all code that should do something with the image or its attributes must be inside your `load`-function, otherwise it will run too early.

Comment: ok! I see, now I understand about that timing issue. 
Anyway I think as Bojan Petkovski is saying the main problem was about I need to set the value outside the function too because I wasnt adding nothing to my variable outside the function

Thank you very much!! you guys saved me! :)

Comment: Bojjan and Martin you saved me too !! thanks for your clear explanations !